# click the text box text a popup menu should open with text box

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- when I click the text box text a popup menu should open with text box.
- similarly when I click a filter icon in the right side corner a menu should open with list of checkboxes.
- but right now whats happening is both the menus are opening when I click at both the places.
- only one menu should open from one location.
- I debugged by putting consoles. the problem is with the below methods

`const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

const handleClickFilter = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };`

- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet  and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kpt5i

```or-tag-here
 const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClickFilter = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleCloseFilter = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle" onClick={handleClickFilter}>
            text box
            <Menu
              id="simple-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              keepMounted
              open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
              onClose={handleCloseFilter}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseFilter}>
                <form
                  className={classes.container}
                  noValidate
                  autoComplete="off"
                >
                  <TextField
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="Name"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    // value={values.name}
                    // onChange={handleChange('name')}
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </form>
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </Typography>

          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
              <FilterListIcon onClick={handleClick} />
              <Menu
                id="simple-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                    value="name"
                  />
                  Dessert
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                    value="calories"
                  />
                  Calories
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleColumnHide}
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
                  />
                  Fat
                </MenuItem>
```

Comment: The way an anchorel works it's that you need to have different anchors depending on what menu you want to display. Due to both your menus are referencing the same achor variable, as soon as that variable get a value set then the Menu component thinks it's being toggled. 

Try using two different anchors (one for each of your menus) and stored them separately on your state. This way each menu will have its own anchor.

Comment: hey can you update in my sandbox so confusing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, you had a couple issues on your code that was preventing this from working properly.

The idea of the 'anchor' element it's that the menu will attach to that DOM object and render right next to it; this is all handled for you by Material and it works like a charm but the thing it's that you need to have this anchors properly set.

First, you need a way to differenciate an anchor element for each menu you want to display (which in your case, it's two).

For this case to work, I used a `'type'` prop inside of your anchor state object and another prop called `'target'` which is the one that will store the `'event.currentTarget'`. Something like this: `{ type: 'icon', target: event.currentTarget }`

Then, you need to have each anchor element (which can be a button, an icon, a label, H1 or whatever you want) separated from the Menu component itself; if you do otherwise, then the Menu will never disappear and it can only be closed using TAB or refreshing. Something like this:

```
<Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
  <span onClick={handleClickFilter}>NOTICE THIS LABEL HAS THE MENU TRIGGER FUNCTION</span>
  <Menu
    id="simple-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl && anchorEl.type === 'textbox' && anchorEl.target}
    open={Boolean(anchorEl && anchorEl.type === 'textbox')}
    onClose={handleClose}
  >
    <MenuItem>
      <form
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <TextField
          label="Name"
          margin="normal"
        />
      </form>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</Typography>
```

Then, finally you need the anchor handler functions, which at this point it's handled by a hook and it's storing with the same variable name except it's modifying the `'type'` prop I mentioned before.

```
const handleClick = event => {
  setAnchorEl({ type: 'textbox', target: event.currentTarget })
}

const handleClose = () => {
  setAnchorEl(null)
}
```

This should do the work successfully.

Anyway, I modified your codepen code and updated it [right here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-rrzp1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey but in the right hand side corner the filter icon got diappaeared in your sandbox, can you tell me how to bring that icon back with check box icon, on each side corner a menu should open `              <FilterListIcon onClick={handleClick} />
`

Comment: Weird, I’m able to see the icon you say it disappeared. I even tested on my phone and it worked (iOS 13.x, Chrome)

Comment: There's no explanation to do here; the icon you say it's gone, I can see it without any issues. [Take a look](http://prntscr.com/pj51rr). I think you might have an error on your code or you removed it by accident.